# Cobol search function line sequential

Tags: search, cobol

This is my code.

```
   SEARCH-RECORD.
       PERFORM SEARCH-OPENING-PROCEDURE.
       PERFORM SEARCH-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       PERFORM SEARCH-RECORDS
           UNTIL CUST-NO = "0".
       PERFORM SEARCH-CLOSING-PROCEDURE.

   SEARCH-OPENING-PROCEDURE.
       OPEN INPUT CUSTOMER-FILE.

   SEARCH-CLOSING-PROCEDURE.
       CLOSE CUSTOMER-FILE.

   SEARCH-RECORDS.
       PERFORM DISPLAY-ALL-FIELDS.
       PERFORM SEARCH-CUSTOMER-RECORD.

   ENTER-CUSTOMER-NO.
       PERFORM ACCEPT-CUSTOMER-NO.
       PERFORM RE-ACCEPT-CUSTOMER-NO
           UNTIL CUST-NO NOT = SPACE.

   ACCEPT-CUSTOMER-NO.
       DISPLAY "ENTER CUSTOMER NO. (EX. C01)".
       DISPLAY "ENTER 0 TO STOP".
       ACCEPT CUST-NO.
       INSPECT CUST-NO
           CONVERTING LOWER-ALPHA
           TO UPPER-ALPHA.

   RE-ACCEPT-CUSTOMER-NO.
       DISPLAY "CUSTOMER NO. MUST BE ENTERED!".
       PERFORM ACCEPT-CUSTOMER-NO.

   SEARCH-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       PERFORM ENTER-CUSTOMER-NO.
       MOVE "N" TO RECORD-FOUND.
       PERFORM FIND-CUSTOMER-NO
           UNTIL RECORD-FOUND = "Y" OR CUST-NO = "0".

   FIND-CUSTOMER-NO.
       PERFORM READ-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       IF RECORD-FOUND = "N"
           DISPLAY "CUSTOMER RECORD NOT FOUND"
           PERFORM ENTER-CUSTOMER-NO.

   READ-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       MOVE "Y" TO RECORD-FOUND.
       READ CUSTOMER-FILE RECORD.

   DISPLAY-ALL-FIELDS.
       DISPLAY " ".
       PERFORM DISPLAY-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       DISPLAY " ".

   DISPLAY-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
       DISPLAY " CUSTOMER NO.: " CUSTOMER-NO.
       DISPLAY "1. CUSTOMER ID: " CUSTOMER-ID.
       DISPLAY "2. CUSTOMER NAME: " CUSTOMER-NAME.
       DISPLAY "3. CUSTOMER PRODUCT: " CUSTOMER-PRODUCT.
       DISPLAY "4. CUSTOMER QUANTITY: " CUSTOMER-QUANTITY.
       DISPLAY "5. CUSTOMER DATE: " CUSTOMER-DATE.
```

Just assume that I have complete records of C01,C02,C03,C04,C05.

My problem is that my CUSTOMER-FILE is in line sequential. So, whenever I try to search for a specific record like C04's record, it always show C01's record first, then C02's, C03's regardless of what I put in my search function. Is there any way that can do custom search? I don't know all the commands, thank you.

Comment: You should look up FILE STATUS in your manual, use it, and check it after each and every IO. Try to structure your program so that you don't have to bounce all over the place whilst reading it. The paragraphs which are `PERFORM`ed should be after those that `PERFORM` them. If you can't arrange it like that, it is a clue indicating tortuous logic.

Comment: +1 on the advice to check file status after every i-o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why your logic always stops after looking at the first record: in `READ-CUSTOMER-RECORD`, you set your record-found flag without checking to see if you have a match (between the record you just read and the customer number you want).  You need to keep reading until you reach the end of file (EOF) or you find the desired customer record.  You need to detect the difference between "I didn't find it on this READ" and "I didn't find it at all."

So you want to change your logic to something like this.  There are cleaner ways to code this, but it's the smallest change to what you have already:

```
SEARCH-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
    PERFORM ENTER-CUSTOMER-NO.
    MOVE "N" TO RECORD-FOUND.
    MOVE "N" TO EOF-FLAG.
    PERFORM FIND-CUSTOMER-NO
        UNTIL RECORD-FOUND = "Y" OR CUST-NO = "0".

FIND-CUSTOMER-NO.
    PERFORM READ-CUSTOMER-RECORD
        UNTIL EOF-FLAG = "Y" OR RECORD-FOUND = "Y".
    IF RECORD-FOUND = "N"
        DISPLAY "CUSTOMER RECORD NOT FOUND"
        PERFORM ENTER-CUSTOMER-NO.

READ-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
    READ CUSTOMER-FILE RECORD
        AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-FLAG.
    IF EOF-FLAG = "N"
        IF CUSTOMER-NO = CUST-NO
            MOVE "Y" TO RECORD-FOUND.
```

If you reach the end of the file, `CUSTOMER-NUMBER` doesn't have a well-defined value.  That's why we have to guard the test with `IF EOF-FLAG = "N"`.  Again, there are other ways to do this, but I'm trying to keep it simple.

A general note on your coding style: there are places where you have redundant code that can be simplified and improved.  Rather than performing `SEARCH-CUSTOMER-RECORD` and then displaying the results in `SEARCH-RECORDS`, you can recode it so that `SEARCH-RECORDS` does the search *and then* the display.

**Update**

One more very important point: when you start a new search, you need to close and re-open `CUSTOMER-FILE`.  (This has the effect of moving the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.)  If you don't do this, your second search will start reading the file from the point you left off, or from the end of file.

There are other file organizations that you will learn about that make this step unnecessary: they allow you to use the [`START` statement](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRLHLHPDFC05.html).

Comment: A `START` on a line-sequential file? `OPEN`/`CLOSE` are usually heavy on processing. With user-input, it won't be so bad, but too many times I see people doing it as a matter of course, and wondering why their programs take so long.

Comment: @BillWoodger I tried to put START, but it says not allowed for sequential file.

Comment: @David Gorsline I get your logic and it helped me with other functions, but this does not solve my search function.

Comment: @BillWoodger I'm hinting to @Jack011 to look into `INDEXED-SEQUENTIAL` or `RELATIVE` file organizations.

Comment: @DavidGorsline I've changed the file mode to INDEXED thanks to you.

Comment: Well, they took your hint. Without the System Spec, no way to know if it is the correct thing to do :-)